# v-support vector regression vs support vector regression

Tags: svm

I have a simple question which googling seems impossible... I would like to know what is the "v" stands for in the v-support vector regression. Is it the same as support vector regression?

Providing some details/real-world applications for each of them to a non-stat/ math background biologist is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to supply some information on the context where you have encountered this. I have come across $\nu$-SVM, where $\nu$ is the Greek letter read as "nu". I'm have yet to come across any real-world applications of this, but that may be an artefact of my limited knowledge of the literature. And in any case $\nu$-SVMs for classification and regression are merely reparametrisations of SVMs, and proposed by [Scholkopf et al. (2000). New support vector algorithms.](https://direct.mit.edu/neco/article/12/5/1207/6368/New-Support-Vector-Algorithms).

Comment: There are is also a brief section on this in *Bishop, C. (2006). Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning.* - see Chapter 7.